# Typescript: es6 import type definition (.d.ts) from node_modules subfolder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I have a npm package that has the following type definitions (simplified):

*./node_modules/ag-grid-react/main.d.ts*

```
export declare class AgGridReact extends Component<AgGridReactProps, {}> {}
```

*./node_modules/ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact.d.ts*

```
export declare class AgGridReact extends Component<AgGridReactProps, {}> {
    gridOptions: GridOptions;
    api: GridApi | null;
    columnApi: ColumnApi;
}
```

I am using the component in my react component like this:

```
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'

const HelpRequests= () => {
  const grid = useRef<AgGridReact>(null)

  if (grid.current) console.log(grid.current.columnApi)

  return (<AgGridReact ref={grid}/>)
}
```

**The Problem:**

Typescript does complain that there is no columnApi. It seems it sadly picks the wrong type from the main.d.ts

I found that I can import the type from the agGridReact.d.ts directly and use it like this:

```
import {AgGridReact as AgGridReactType} from 'ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact'

...

const grid = useRef<AgGridReactType>(null)
```

**Question:**

Is this the correct way to address this issue? Will typescript be smart enough not to import the  *./node_modules/ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact.ts* file which could cause my bundle size to go up?

I've searched a lot but could not find anything about importing types only from node_modules subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer this:

Let's assume there is an `xyz` library and it has these files:

**xyz/lib/main.ts:**

```
export const test = 1000
```

and

**xyz/main.ts:**

```
export * from './lib/main.ts'
export const test = 'foo bar'
```

And I would like to use `xyz` in my **app.ts**, and I am aware of only its **main.ts** file as I think it is the main file which exports everything from library. So I am most likely to do:

**app.ts:**

```
import { test } from './xyz/main'

console.debug(test) // it will print 'foo bar'
```

Now, somebody goes and comment this line in the library:

**xyz/main.ts:**

```
export * from './lib/main.ts'
// export const test = 'foo bar'
```

Now, what will be printed by my **app.ts**? It will print `1000`.

---

The same thing is happening there with `ag-grid-react`. It (**ag-grid-react/main.d.ts**) is **overriding** the apparently correct (better) class declaration present in **ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact.d.ts**. And it is perfectly fine to import from **inner path**.

**main.d.ts:**

```
export * from './lib/agGridReact'; // it is exporting from innner path too
export declare class AgGridColumn extends Component<AgGridColumnProps | AgGridColumnGroupProps, {}> { // and overriding here at the same time
}
```

**agGridReact.d.ts:**

```
export declare class AgGridReact extends Component<AgGridReactProps, {}> {
    props: any;
    state: any;
    static propTypes: any;
    gridOptions: GridOptions;
    changeDetectionService: ChangeDetectionService;
    api: GridApi | null;
    columnApi: ColumnApi;
    portals: ReactPortal[];
    hasPendingPortalUpdate: boolean;
    destroyed: boolean;
    protected eGridDiv: HTMLElement;
    private static MAX_COMPONENT_CREATION_TIME;
    constructor(props: any, state: any);
    render(): React.ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => React.ReactElement<any, string | any | (new (props: any) => React.Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => React.Component<any, any, any>)>;
    createStyleForDiv(): any;
    componentDidMount(): void;
    waitForInstance(reactComponent: ReactComponent, resolve: (value: any) => void, runningTime?: number): void;
    mountReactPortal(portal: ReactPortal, reactComponent: ReactComponent, resolve: (value: any) => void): void;
    batchUpdate(callback?: any): any;
    destroyPortal(portal: ReactPortal): void;
    private getStrategyTypeForProp;
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: any): boolean;
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: any): void;
    processPropsChanges(prevProps: any, nextProps: any): void;
    private extractDeclarativeColDefChanges;
    private extractGridPropertyChanges;
    componentWillUnmount(): void;
    isDisableStaticMarkup(): boolean;
}
```

I can't exactly say why `ag-grid` did this. I found this looking at the typing files. I may be incorrect too.

Comment: Will typescript be smart enough not to import the ./node_modules/ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact.ts file which could cause my bundle size to go up?

Comment: No. TS doesn't do that. When you import, TS considers path and imported item, it doesn't care about bundle size at this time. Also, TS is only to ease development work. At the end, in the browser or a server, it is pure JS. Bundle size goes up / down by what you write and use (from library) in your code.

Comment: @pa1nd types exist on compile-time only, so even if TypeScript will use it - it won't cause bundle size to go up.

Comment: @Slaus I'm not worried about the .d.ts but about the .ts file with the same name! Because my import ... from '' does not specify the file-ending. So it could e understood as .ts (which it probably is, right?)

Comment: @pa1nd not sure, but, anyway, if you have any build system (webpack probably?) it only includes functions (classes are just constructor functions) you call from your main module - regardless of files you import. So I don't think there should be a reason to worry about bundle growth.